# hiding overlapped text is failing in case of linear gradient

Tags: javascript, html, css

[image: This is the gradient]i was trying the code shown in this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/2aWcV/

how to remove the overlap if "$number" can have any number of  digits and we dont know its size as the number of digits is fetched from some other file.($number is a random number generated) $number must have an opaque background so that the text underneath it doesn't show through.(text must be to the left of $number

The html code is:

```
<div class="body">     
    <div class="variation font700 green"> 
        <h2> 
            overflown text must be hidden and the visible text  must be in single line
            <span class="divider"> 
                $number 
            </span>
        </h2>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>  
</div>
```

And this works perfectly fine when we have a background as a single color rather than a gradient why is that so and here is the link to the fiddle with background as a single color:
http://jsfiddle.net/Re9ZN/
Can someone give me a solution so that it works well when we have a gradient.

Answer (score 1):

Following code should do the trick for you.

Change to this in your css class:

```
.variation h2 span{
    background: linear-gradient(to left, #339933,#003300);
    position:absolute;
    right:0;

}
```

**DEMO** : http://jsfiddle.net/Akki619/xzW6A/

**For your comment EDIT 1**

You can use below code, please update colors as per your need. It covers all the browsers.

```
 background-color: #F07575; /* fallback color if gradients are not supported */
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For Chrome and Safari */
  background-image:    -moz-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Fx (3.6 to 15) */
  background-image:     -ms-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For pre-releases of IE 10*/
  background-image:      -o-linear-gradient(top, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* For old Opera (11.1 to 12.0) */ 
  background-image:         linear-gradient(to bottom, hsl(0, 80%, 70%), #bada55); /* Standard syntax; must be last */
```

**NOTE: Answers can not expected the way you desired, it should be considered as "to get you started."**

This below image is max I can help you out as far as gradient goes. As sections are divided, I don't think with current implementation it is possible.

[image]

**CSS CODE:**

```
background: #7fbf70; /* Old browsers */
background: -moz-linear-gradient(left,  #7fbf70 0%, #76b868 1%, #73b766 2%, #60ac5a 4%, #48a04d 10%, #3c9a47 13%, #309643 19%, #289441 27%, #289341 41%, #168b3e 47%, #08893d 49%, #00853c 52%, #005b28 88%, #005424 96%, #005424 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, color-stop(0%,#7fbf70), color-stop(1%,#76b868), color-stop(2%,#73b766), color-stop(4%,#60ac5a), color-stop(10%,#48a04d), color-stop(13%,#3c9a47), color-stop(19%,#309643), color-stop(27%,#289441), color-stop(41%,#289341), color-stop(47%,#168b3e), color-stop(49%,#08893d), color-stop(52%,#00853c), color-stop(88%,#005b28), color-stop(96%,#005424), color-stop(100%,#005424)); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left,  #7fbf70 0%,#76b868 1%,#73b766 2%,#60ac5a 4%,#48a04d 10%,#3c9a47 13%,#309643 19%,#289441 27%,#289341 41%,#168b3e 47%,#08893d 49%,#00853c 52%,#005b28 88%,#005424 96%,#005424 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
background: -o-linear-gradient(left,  #7fbf70 0%,#76b868 1%,#73b766 2%,#60ac5a 4%,#48a04d 10%,#3c9a47 13%,#309643 19%,#289441 27%,#289341 41%,#168b3e 47%,#08893d 49%,#00853c 52%,#005b28 88%,#005424 96%,#005424 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
background: -ms-linear-gradient(left,  #7fbf70 0%,#76b868 1%,#73b766 2%,#60ac5a 4%,#48a04d 10%,#3c9a47 13%,#309643 19%,#289441 27%,#289341 41%,#168b3e 47%,#08893d 49%,#00853c 52%,#005b28 88%,#005424 96%,#005424 100%); /* IE10+ */
background: linear-gradient(to right,  #7fbf70 0%,#76b868 1%,#73b766 2%,#60ac5a 4%,#48a04d 10%,#3c9a47 13%,#309643 19%,#289441 27%,#289341 41%,#168b3e 47%,#08893d 49%,#00853c 52%,#005b28 88%,#005424 96%,#005424 100%); /* W3C */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#7fbf70', endColorstr='#005424',GradientType=1 ); /* IE6-9 */
```

Comment: The gradient is not looking linear throught the div. what should i do in this case in order to have linear gradient throught?

Comment: Use this to generate you gradient for almost all the browsers support http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

Comment: In your updated fiddle the gradient is not linear from start of the div to end of it.(i.e. it is starting a new gradient from that divider). can u please give me a solution where the gradient is linear from start of the div to the end of it??

Comment: can you please update your question by posting sample gradient images you are looking for.

Comment: can u please check the uploaded color

Comment: and i need the gradient to be linear till the tip of the arrow